# Do I have to split up my React app to use subdomains with NGINX?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, subdomain, web-deployment

I currently have a single React app for 3 "parts" of a website. NGINX handles the requests as a reverse proxy and users can access the web app by visiting:
`myDomain.com/...` for the public website (simple web presence of the company).
`myDomain.com/company/...` for the company side (staff manages data here).
`myDomain.com/clients/...` for the clients of the company (clients log in and see progress of purchased services etc.).

Instead I want to access the different parts with subdomains:
`myDomain.com/...` for the public website.
`company.myDomain.com/...` for the company side.
`client.myDomain.com/...` for the client side.

**Now my two questions are:**

1. Is the only option to split my single react app into 3 distinct apps and use NGINX to point to each of the apps according to requested subdomains? What other solutions are there?
2. I want to avoid splitting the react app because I want to share react components and css styles across the 3 different parts of the app. If I split the react app, I guess I have to duplicate the react components and css styles. Is that true or is there a more DRY approach if I do end up splitting my react app?

Thank you!

Comment: You can serve your react app from subdomains just as you're serving it from url paths.

Comment: Hmm I guess I have to dive into the NGINX docs then, or do you think I can implement subdomains with react-router?

Comment: You can do it in react by reading the subdomain from `window.location` and then conditionally rendering the required part. From nginx, you can just serve the whole app for wildcard subdomain and do the conditional rendering in react.

Comment: Ah that seems pretty simple actually. Ill give that a try for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Check out `Netlify` for subdomain routing.

As for Nginx, you can serve them from one file like so:

```
server {
    server_name myDomain.com
    root /src/path/to/comp1
}
server {
    server_name company.myDomain.com
    root /src/path/to/comp2
}
server {
    server_name client.myDomain.com
    root /src/path/to/comp3
}
```

Comment: Cool, I will first try out xyres solution (as written in his comment), since that might be easiest. But thank you for taking time out of your day, I appreciate it! It seems to be a rather simple matter, so I realize I should spend some time in the NGINX docs.